# Android: Google Maps v2 API loading blank map on Android 4.0 and above

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Android v2 in my Android project.

I have tested on 3 devices: HTC Vivid (4.0.3), Asus Nexus 7 (4.2.2), and a Galaxy S2 (2.2). The map only shows up on the Galaxy S2 using the above information, so I know that everything SHOULD work fine.

Question: What do I need to do to add compatibility, or simply fix the errors with the higher API versions?

I have done the following:

- Generated the keystores (both debug and custom) and registered both of their SHA-1 codes with package name to the Google APIs Console. I have tried the program with both API keys and both returned the same blank screen and error. Using the program out of debug mode shows that attempts were made to access the API in the report logs in the console.
- Imported the android-support-v4.jar file
- Imported the google-play-services_lib project folder, set it as a library, and configured my project to use that library.
- Set up my "my_map.xml" layout with the following code

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
  ```
- Set up my Activity Class with the following code

  ```
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;

  public class MapActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.my_map);

  GoogleMap map = 
              ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
              .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new
              LatLng(34.739849,-92.307129)).title("SwagString"));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
  return true;
  }
  }
  ```
- I have all required permissions
- I have added the meta-data for the key into my AndroidManifest.xml
- Permissions:

  ```
  <permission
  android:name="com.uaex.droughtadvisor.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.uaex.droughtadvisor.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  ```
- Meta-Data

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  ```
- Upon running the code on the 4.0 and above devices, i get this error:

  ```
  Failed to load map. Error contacting Google Servers.
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263328/getting-failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers might help

Comment: I tried that solution, it did not work.

Comment: *the report logs in the console* - what did that say? I recently found myself in a similar situation after deploying a debug app with a live key. Simply swapping out the key for the correct one didn't make the map work, until I completely removed and reinstalled the app.

Comment: The console shows nothing strange. Logcat only reports the error i posted above. As I said, it worked fine running it on a device running Android 2.2, so I don't see how it could be an issue with the API key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it was, but I got it working. Initially I was targeting 2.2, then I downloaded the other versions in my SDK manager and tried those (just 4.0.3 and 4.2.2, as those were the versions of my test devices). I targeted those and installed them on their respective devices and it worked. Moving back down to 2.2, they still worked, when originally they didn't. No idea what happened here, but I'm fine now.

Comment: Chances are, by switching the target level, you caused a recompile of all your code (like doing a clean + build). This probably fixed whatever mangled classes you had previously and perhaps, just like the other user in the related question above. Glad you are back on top of things :)