# Google map app NOT working in android

Tags: android

I am a new android developer.
I have made android google map app,
but it is showing only empty tiles (not showing map)

I have generated 5 times API key & used it...but no one is working

**Manifiest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.akki"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" >
    </uses-permission>`enter code here`

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GoogleMapPracticeActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMh2JQY"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: using google map api v1. its deprecated use map api v2.

Comment: try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263328/getting-failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers/17269641#17269641

Answer (score 1):

Use Map v2 and you can found tutorial from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start